# Oracle net configuration assistant

Tags: oracle

In Oracle net configuration assistant  I am not able to select reconfiger, delete or rename.please help i tried to add a listener but when I create database there no listener name,port and the status.

Comment: What do you mean "when I create database there no listener name,port and the status."?  Exactly what are you looking at and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: I expecting to see my listener name, port number and status of a listener while creating a database

Answer (score 0):

If you successfully added a listener using Net Config Assist, at the completion of that you'd see a screen saying "Listener Configuration Completed Successfully". This also starts the listener. Did you see that?

You can also start a terminal/command prompt and run:

```
lsnrctl status XXX
```

where XXX is the name of the listener you created (Default = LISTENER) to see if it is running.

Another possible issue is that if you have multiple installations of Oracle on the same box. You may have created a listener under one installation and be trying to install the database under another installation. The listener might not be picked up in this instance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did  that..it shows me the status but when I want to create a new database I cannot see my listener name,port number and listener status

Comment: Creating a database has nothing to do with listeners.  Oracle is quite happy to run with no listener at all.  Exactly _where_ is it in creating a database that you expect to see anything about a listener?

Comment: presumably if he's using netca to configure a listener, he's using dbca to create the database, and that will prompt for a listener to use during the wizard